# Converting docker run to python docker, issues passing environmental variables

Tags: docker, python-docker

I'm trying to convert the following docker run command to python docker run:

```
docker run -v ${HOME}/mypath/somepath:/root/mypath/somepath:ro -v /tmp/report/:/root/report -e MY_VAR=fooname DOCKER_IMAGE
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run(DOCKER_IMAGE, 'MY_VAR=fooname', volumes={
    f'{home}/mypath/somepath': {'bind': '/root/mypath/somepath', 'mode': 'ro'},
    '/tmp/report': {'bind': '/root/report', 'mode': 'rw'},
},)
```

But it seems like I'm running into issues when passing the env variables

```
docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"MY_VAR=fooname\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown")
```

What's the right way to pass the env variables?

EDIT

After changing it to

```
client.containers.run(DOCKER_IMAGE, None, environment=['MY_VAR=fooname'], volumes={
    f'{home}/mypath/somepath': {'bind': '/root/mypath/somepath', 'mode': 'ro'},
    '/tmp/report': {'bind': '/root/report', 'mode': 'rw'},
},)
```

I'm getting this error instead: `docker.errors.ContainerError: Command 'None' in image`

The docker build file has the command declared to just run a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the `run()` method is the command, not the environment. If you don't have a command then pass `None`.

According to the documentation the `environment` must be either a dict or a list, so in your case:

```
client.containers.run(DOCKER_IMAGE, None, environment=['MY_VAR=fooname'], ...
```

Docs: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run

Comment: Hmm I'm running into `docker.errors.ContainerError: Command 'None' in image '{DOCKER_IMAGE}' returned non-zero exit status 1`

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat weird, maybe are you passing None as a string? Looking at the function signature it shows that it will default to `None` if no command is passed so it shouldn't require one.

Comment: There must've been a typo somewhere, I rewrote the run command and it started working :) Thank you